# Persist shell across multiple sh calls in a groovy jenkins pipline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have two groovy functions within a Jenkins pipeline that together logs into an ECR repo and builds a docker container. It looks like this:

```
def login() {
    sh "aws ecr get-login --registry-ids <id> --region <region> --no-include-email"
    sh "aws ecr get-login --region <region> --no-include-email"
}

def build(project, tag) {    
    login()
    sh "docker build -t ${project}:${tag} ."
}
```

However, when I run this, I get `pull access denied`, as if I never logged in. I surmise this is because the aws ecr login commands ran in their own shells, and the build commands ran in another. Ideally, I'd like to leverage this kind of functional decomposition and other features of groovy, but run shell commands in one process/shell. Is this possible? How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why not to put all those commands in one `sh` ?

Comment: Basically because if I did that, I wouldn't be able to re-use functions. For example, if I had another, e.g. `push`, I'd ideally want to re-use the `login` function without having to copy and paste those lines wherever I need them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that [`aws ecr get-login` returns a string](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login.html) containing the command to login to your registry. You will need to execute the result of that command, by assigning the output of the command to a variable and then executing that result, like so:

```
def login() {
    loginRegistry = sh (script: "aws ecr get-login --registry-ids <id> --region <region> --no-include-email", returnStdout: true)
    sh loginRegistry

    loginRegion = sh (script: "aws ecr get-login --region <region> --no-include-email", returnStdout: true)
    sh loginRegion
}

def build(project, tag) {    
    login()
    sh "docker build -t ${project}:${tag} ."
}
```

Comment: Once I added returnStdout: true for both login statements, this absolutely works! Thanks so much. So I take it that all groovy code actually runs in the same shell?